# Vector Space And Sub Space

Tags: linear-algebra

A vector space need to follow [the 8 axioms](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/121.1.00s/vector_axioms.html), while sub-space needs to be non-empty and closed to linear combinations.
So for a given vector set, all I can do is to prove that it is a sub-group of a bigger vector space and to prove that is non-empty and closed to linear combinations?
Is there an example to a vector space that is not a sub space of a bigger vector space?

Comment: I think that every vector space $V$ is a subspace of a bigger vector space - of $V\oplus V$, for instance.

Comment: Or even of its own :)

Comment: @JankoBracic what is the vector space of $R^2 \oplus R^2$? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that almost every concrete vector space over$~K$ that one cares about in practice can be realised as a subspace or as a subquotient (quotient of a subspace) of some space $K^S$ of functions $S\to K$ for some set$~S$ (or a space obviously isomorphic to it, such as $K^n$ for $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$), equipped with the standard operations of addition and scalar multiplication of functions. So after you checked that $K^S$ satisfies the vector space axioms, as well as any subspace or quotient of a known vector space (which is easy), you will very rarely have to use those axioms to actually check that something is a vector space. You do need the axioms all the time as *given* when building up the abstract theory of vector spaces (linear algebra).

Comment: Does the same goes to $P[X]$ polynomial space?

Comment: Yes, $K[X]$ is a subspace of the space $K[[X]]$ of formal power series (drop the condition that coefficients must become zero ultimately) which naturally is isomorphic to (or even defined as) the space $K^\Bbb N$ of maps $\Bbb N\to K$ assigning a coefficient (of $X^n$) to each $n\in\Bbb N$.